# Logic Behind the Convention of the Result of Modulo Operations

Tags: arithmetic

Consider the following 4 results

```
 7 %  3 =  1
-7 %  3 =  2
 7 % -3 = -2 
-7 % -3 = -1
```

I'm struggling to see why these outputs have been selected as such

`7 % 3` is clear. Imagining `|` as `0`, I can chunk up `7` into `3` groups of 3, and I have `1` left over going away from `|`

```
|*** *** *** *
```

Of course, we could say this is `-1` as in "take away 1 from your numerator to make it divisible" or we could say it's `-2` or `2`, they all represent in some way how far off we are from having a perfect divisor.

The convention for `-7 % 3` is odd to me, but I can reason about it. I would've thought it was `-1` (`3` groups of 3 and a remaining `-1`), but it's `2`. I guess that's just convention.

```
* *** *** ***|
```

I'm really struggling reasoning about `7 % -3` and `-7 % -3`, though. Can someone explain this to me so I can intuitively understand this operation more quickly?

Side note, if I were creating a remainder operator, it would have these results

```
 7 %  3 =  1 # remaining 1
-7 %  3 = -1 # remaining -1
 7 % -3 = -1 # -ve version of 7 % 3
-7 % -3 =  1 # same as 7 % 3
```

Comment: Of course `%` is implemented in a certain computer language or calculator.  Since mathematicians do not use that notation, perhaps this is better asked of the implementors of the computer language or calculator.

Comment: Maple does this: $$7 \mod 3 = 1;\\(-7) \mod 3 = 2;\\7 \mod (-3) = 1; \\(-7) \mod (-3) = 2;$$The meaning is "remainder on division" where $$7 = (2)(3)+1\\-7 = (-3)(3)+2\\7 = (-2)(-3)+1\\-7 = (3)(-3)+2$$